# MySQL trigger to insert a record in a table after INSERT in another table

Tags: triggers, path, tree, insert, mariadb

Having two MySQL tables, first one storing a tree built according an adjacency list model, second being an helper table storing the path to each node.

The question is/was how to set a trigger, so that after an insert in the adjacency table, a record storing the path record is inserted in to the helper table.

The idea is the same as here: https://kod34fr33.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/adjacency-list-tree-on-mysql/
but with the following differences:

- no record should be stored in the helper table if the node's direct
  parent is the root (which has id=0)
- not storing the id of the record at the end of the path
- no leading nor trailing slashes in the path
- "." delimitor instead of "/"

Table structures:

- Adjacency table: "prefix_productcategories" columns
  `id`,`parent`,`name`.
- Helper table "prefix_prodcat_path" columns are : `id`,`path`
- `id`,`parent` are SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED
- `path` is TEXT.

After several corrections to my initial code, I could correct the syntax errors.
So, here's one possible **solution** for MariaDB (and probably for MySQL too), hoping it can help others:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `insertProdCatPathRecord` AFTER INSERT ON `prefix_productcategories`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE `path_of_parent` TEXT DEFAULT '';
  IF (NEW.`parent` > 0) THEN
    SELECT `path` INTO `path_of_parent` FROM `prefix_prodcat_path` WHERE `prefix_prodcat_path`.`id`= NEW.`parent`;
    IF (SELECT FOUND_ROWS()) THEN
      INSERT INTO `prefix_prodcat_path` VALUES (NEW.`id`,CONCAT(NEW.`parent`,'.',NEW.`id`));
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO `prefix_prodcat_path` VALUES(NEW.`id`,NEW.`parent`);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: When you create procedure/function/trigger, you should use your temporary delimiter after this procedure: `END//`

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry for the typos. Any idea what 's wrong with the syntax?
If I remove the "DECLARE ..." line and the "INTO ...", the syntax error stays on the "SELECT ..." line.

Comment: Things that I learned when cleaning my code: 1) the semicolons are necessary after the END IF and the END keywords. 2) for some reason trying to CAST() numeric values to TEXT into the CONCAT() function was not working. Probably does CONCAT() make the necessery casting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what I've found so far. You don't have keywords `THEN` related to `IF`, as well as you do have `END` instead of `END IF`. The syntax of `DECLARE` is wrong, you can't set default values. Also, don't know what's @@ROWCOUNT. (Edit: found it, it's related to MS SQL Server, but isn't used in MySQL.)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insertProdCatPathRecord AFTER INSERT ON prefix_productcategories 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (NEW.parent > 0) THEN
    DECLARE path_of_parent TEXT;
    SET path_of_parent='';
    SELECT path INTO path_of_parent FROM prefix_prodcat_path WHERE prefix_prodcat_path.id= NEW.parent;
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT) THEN
        INSERT INTO prefix_prodcat_path VALUES(NEW.id,CONCAT(NEW.parent,'.',NEW.id));
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO prefix_prodcat_path VALUES(NEW.id,NEW.parent);
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for having mentioned those syntax errors that I corrected. I removed the 'path_of_parent' temporary variable as the CONCAT is done within the first INSERT statement. I removed several BEGIN ... END sandwiches as well. I posted my second attempt in the original post. Unfortunately, there is still a syntax error near the first INSERT.

Comment: Solution found. See original post.